# Use Word for `*`/`#`

Tags: normal-mode, keyword, vi-words

As a lot of people, I have removed `_` from `iskeyword`, so it considers it kind of like whitespace. This is really useful for changing part of an identifier in languages like Python and Rust with normal commands like `w`, `e` and `b`. However, it also breaks `*` and `#`. Does (Neo)Vim have an option / plugin to force these to use Words instead? :)

Comment: "As a lot of people" [citation needed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` is *roughly* equivalent to searching for the string:

```
'\<' . escape(expand('<cword>'), '/.*~[^$\') . '\>'
```

(the escape is slightly different for #).  So, one option is to create a custom mapping which uses WORDs instead of words (`<c-r><c-a>` means cWORD).

```
nnoremap <silent> * /<c-r>=escape('<c-r><c-a>', '/.*~[^$\')<cr>/<cr>
nnoremap <silent> # ?<c-r>=escape('<c-r><c-a>', '/?.*~[^$\')<cr>?<cr>
```

On the other hand, this is not necessarily useful, for example,

```
else if (tag_cmd) ...
```

pressing `*` on `tag_cmd` will search for literal `(tag_cmd)`.  Also, in vim, `#` always skips the current word unlike this implementation.

Another idea is to temporarily remove `_` from `iskeyword`:

```
nnoremap * <cmd>se isk-=_<cr>*<cmd>se isk+=_<cr>
nnoremap # <cmd>se isk-=_<cr>#<cmd>se isk+=_<cr>
```

Since `*` is implemented using `/` and `?` as described above, `n` and `N` will continue to work.

Comment: Nice solution 

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution - since 0.8.0, neovim supports * and # on visual selections, so you can select it manually, or make a shortcut

Source https://youtu.be/TX_uOJiIjcM